# MongoDB query with a LEFT JOIN

Tags: json, mongodb, find, left-join

I am doing a mongodb query or I was using a LEFT JOIN for the SQL database.

Here is the document of a profil :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd22f28f77cfb1f6ce503ca"),
    "search" : "flarize",
    "name" : "flarize",
    "email" : "flarize.ba73@gmail.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$eYeOtEkEUyD7TFkjKvhZOuSSpvBolkL17TrPHuoHhOT8JrsQR0UKW",
    "color" : 0,
    "profil" : "",
    "banner" : "",
    "desc" : "",
    "date" : 1540501286109,
    "friend" : [
            {
                    "id" : ObjectId("5bd19a92da24674fdabd26b6")
            }
    ],
    "groupes" : [ ]
}
```

I am currently using this request:

```
db.users.find({search: /f/}).limit(20);
```

this query just given profile according to the regex.

may I want more, if the id of the person who call this query is present in the section friend then we add :

```
is_friend: true
```

else add:

```
is_friend: false
```

**EDIT :**

For this query we have:

The id of the who call the request, and whe try to know if this id is present in the friend field.

**EDIT**

I try this but not working, return false.

```
herdb.users.aggregate([{$match:{"search":"flarize"}},
    {$project:
        {search: 1, name: 1, color: 1, profil: 1, banner: 1, desc: 1, date: 1, friend:10, groupes:10, 
        is_friend:
            {$cond:[
                {$eq:["$friend.id", ObjectId("5bd19a92da24674fdabd26b6")]},
                true, 
                false]
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty();
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Where you want to add `is_friend`? Can you share sample input and output data to the better understanding?

Comment: at the end of the document

Comment: according to who calls the request is friend takes the value of either true or false

Comment: And you want to store back to the database with is_friend = true or false..right?

Comment: I tried this, but it's still not working, return always false. db.users.aggregate([{$match:{"search":"flarize"}},{$project:{search: 1, name: 1, color: 1, profil: 1, banner: 1, desc: 1, date: 1, friend:10, groupes:10, is_friend:{$cond:[{$eq:["$friend.id", ObjectId("5bd19a92da24674fdabd26b6")]},true, false]}}}]).pretty();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$unwind` for a friend before matching it's `id`

`$eq` is not working for an array.

```
db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([
    { $match: {"search":"flarize"} },
    { $unwind: "$friend"},
    { $project:{
        search: 1, name: 1, color: 1, profil: 1, banner: 1, desc: 1, date: 1, friend:10, groupes:10,
        is_friend: { $cond: [
            { $eq :["$friend.id", ObjectId("5bd19a92da24674fdabd26b6")]}, true,  false ]}
        }
    }
]);
```

**Output:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd22f28f77cfb1f6ce503ca"),
    "search" : "flarize",
    "name" : "flarize",
    "color" : 0,
    "profil" : "",
    "banner" : "",
    "desc" : "",
    "date" : NumberLong(1540501286109),
    "friend" : {
        "id" : ObjectId("5bd19a92da24674fdabd26b6"),
        "id" : ObjectId("5bd19a92da24674fdabd26b4"),
        "id" : ObjectId("5bd19a92da24674fdabd26b2"),
        "id" : ObjectId("5bd19a92da24674fdabd26b1")
    },
    "groupes" : [],
    "is_friend" : true
}
```

---

And if you want `friend` back it to an array list:

```
db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([
    { $match: {"search":"flarize"} },
    { $unwind: "$friend"},
    { $project:
        {
            search: 1, name: 1, color: 1, profil: 1, banner: 1, desc: 1, date: 1, friend:10, groupes:10,
            is_friend: { $cond: [
                { $eq :["$friend.id", ObjectId("5bd19a92da24674fdabd26b6")]}, true,  false ]}
        }
    },
    {$group : {
        _id: "$_id",
        search : {$first: "$search"},
        name : {$first: "$name"},
        color : {$first: "$color"},
        profil : {$first: "$profil"},
        banner : {$first: "$banner"},
        desc : {$first: "$desc"},
        date : {$first: "$date"},
        groupes : {$first: "$groupes"},
        friend : {$push: "$friend"},
        is_friend: {$first: "$is_friend"}
     }}
])
```